# Dynamically show row selection checkbox in angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angular-ui-grid

I have checkbox in each row for selecting particular row.

I need to hide that checkbox in mobile view. I am using `ui-grid-selection`

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions"  ui-grid-selection ui-grid-pagination class="grid"></div>
```

I tried

```
 gridOptions.enableRowSelection= false
 gridOptions.enableSelectAll = false;
```

nothing worked. Any Idea?